# Eclipse JRE system libraries reset after restart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

We are using Eclipse Kepler (Build id: 20130614-0229) with the JDK 1.7_25. One of our projects requires Java FX. Since it is not part of the standard system library, we are adding it in Eclipse to the JRE Definition as a system library (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit).

The Problem is that this path gets reset when we restart Eclipse and hence compile errors appear in the Java FX Project. Does anyone know, how to to fix this issue, or what plugin could cause this behavior? (We are using the Attlassian Connector Plugin, the Google and GWT Plugin and Subversive Connectors Plugin).

Comment: I don't know how to fix your particular configuration, but if you change to using the [e(fx)clipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org) and/or [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), your issues should go away.

Comment: I doubt that the issu is caused by Eclipse in the startup, but who know... If you want to investigate go to Preference -> General -> Startup and Shutdown. Disable all the plugins at the startup and see if the problem is solved, if so enable one plugin and see which one is the cause.

Comment: Turns out, that this behavior is still observable with all plugins disabled on startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) and adding the JAVA FX SDK Library to the build path of the project works as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 should have JavaFX included. You should not need to do anything to explicitly include it.

Comment: That is correct - the jar file is located in the folder jre/lib. However it is not included as a system library in the JRE Definition in Eclipse.